# Почему часть блока убегает на другую сторону? (css)

Tags: html, css, html5, css-animation, bootstrap4

```
.greed-wrapper {
    columns: 2;
    column-gap: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

<div class="row greed-wrapper">
   <div class="wrapper-menu-category"></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите почему часть блока убегает на другую сторону и как это можно исправить, чтобы блоки не расращивали?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно обернуть одним дивом блок с фото и описанием. У вас прилибизительно схематично сейчас так.
`<div class="photo"></div><div class="opisanie"></div>`.
А нужно чтобы эти два дива були внутри одного. Вот так
`<div class="wrap"><div class="photo"></div><div class="opisanie"></div></div>` Классы, написанные в ответе придуманы для показа.